# Array to string conversion, Validação Laravel

Tags: upload, validação, laravel-5

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/dashboard/category/{{$action}}">
...
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Imagem</label>
        <input type="file" id="image" name="img">
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

ControllerPost:

```
use Validator;

....

$rules = array('img' => 'image|max:1024*1024');
$messages = array(
    'img.image' => 'Só pode ser uma imagem (jpg, gif ou png)',
    'img.max' => 'ficheiro muito pesado... upload máximo é 1 MB'
);

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
}
else {
    dd('heya');
}
```

Quando faço upload do ficheiro aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> ErrorException in FileLoader.php line 109: Array to string conversion

Alguém o porquê e como resolver?

Comment: widthErrors ou withErrors? Vamos começar a fazer essa pequena correção.

Comment: Qual é a linha 109? o erro basicamente diz, que você tentou manipular um array com uma função de scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A própria mensagem da exceção já diz o que está havendo.

**Não é possível converter o array para string porque o campo "img" é um array.**

Todo campo do tipo file gera um array no php.

Dessa maneira: $_FILES['img']

Onde você tem:

```
$_FILES['img']['name'] // nome real do arquivo na sua maquina
$_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] // nome temporário do arquivo
$_FILES['img']['size'] //Tamanho do arquivo em bytes
$_FILES['img']['type'] // Tipo / mime extensão do arquivo
$_FILES['img']['error'] // Erros ocorridos na tentativa de envio
```

E para fazer uploads de arquivo no laravel, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$path = $request->file('img')->storeAs('pastaDeUpload');
```

**Para mais informações:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads